# Loss function increases dramatically after transfer learning (or parameters initialization)

Tags: machine-learning, convolutional-neural-networks

I am modeling a CNN network with some customized layers that performs 2D FFT and IFFT, I have a dataset with features representing time domain OFDM symbols, and labels representing frequency domain OFDM constellation samples.

The network is modeled as follows : [some CONV2D layers with activation 'tanh' and BN ---> FFT layer ---> some CONV2D layers with activation 'tanh' and BN ---> IFFT layer ---> some CONV2D layers with activation 'tanh' and BN] this entire block repeated several times.

The network have to produce the same input shape at the output (exactly 1x1024 matrices with 2 channels i.e. (None, 1, 1024,2)).

I trained the model's parts between FFT and IFFT layers separately and I used the obtained parameters for the full model initialization.

After that I got very good loss (only for forward propagation i.e. prediction without training), but after that when I tried to train the model to get lower loss, it directly increased the loss from 7e-6 to 1.9.
I would like to ask for some help to identify the possible problem, is it from the optimizer itself (maybe it did not take this initialization in consideration, some flag should be set or ...)? Or the problem can be from the network it self? Or maybe I need to add some extra trainable layers and try transfer learning from the base model and make it as untrainable?

- I am using tensorflow/keras as library.
- The loss function = mean squared error.
- Optimizer => I used SGD and Adam.
- The CONV2D layers are modeled as conv2d depthwise separable layers.

Thank you.